# NodaTime IANA TimeZone Offsets not matching in C#

Tags: c#, nodatime

**Date to convert :** 12/10/2016 12:00:00 AM
**Time zone to convert :** America/New_York

This is my function to return offset of the date (dt) I provide.

```
LocalDateTime fromLocal = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt);
DateTimeZone fromZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
ZonedDateTime fromZoned = fromLocal.InZoneLeniently(fromZone);

return fromZoned.ToDateTimeOffset();
```

**Result :** 2016-12-10T00:00:00 America/New_York (-05)

When I google offset for America/New_York, I get **-04** as offset.

Please help if anybody knows why this is happening.

Comment: Daylight savings?

Comment: Rather than "When I google offset for America/New_York" it would be useful if you'd cite *specific* sources, because then it would be easier to point out whether the source is correct and you've misunderstood it, or whether the source itself is incorrect. If your search found the *current* UTC offset, then that would indeed be UTC-4 - but half the point of time zones is that the offset at one point in time can be different from the offset at another point in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I google offset for America/New_York, I get -04 as offset.

That would be true in the summer (and in particular it's the *current* offset at the time of your question), but not the winter (which would include 2016-12-10 - your "12/10/2016" is ambiguous in terms of whether it's in December or October).

America/New_York observes UTC-5 in winter, and UTC-4 in summer.

There's no bug here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jon Skeet. Do you have idea on NodaTime..? When i compare/convert between 2 time zones for past date (in my example); If source is New_York and Target is antigua timezone, is that library considers present DST or The date's DST which i am using?

Comment: @PraveenPatelG: When doing a conversion, Noda Time *always* uses the offset at the time of the value being converted. It would be very, very wrong to use the present value - i.e. for the conversion of a fixed value to change depending on when the code was running. If that's not what you meant, please ask a new question with a concrete example.